# Mysql 5.1 Native query to transform into nested JSON array

Tags: php, mysql, json

I have the following two tables;

Defaults:

```
 Consultant  ¦ Company
-------------+----------- 
Consultant 1 ¦ Company 1  
Consultant 2 ¦ Company 1  
Consultant 3 ¦ Company 1  
Consultant 4 ¦ Company 2  
Consultant 5 ¦ Company 3  
Consultant 6 ¦ Company 4
```

And GP:

```
Week Number ¦ Weekending ¦  Month  ¦ quarter ¦ Year  ¦ Consultant   ¦ Type ¦ Total
------------+------------+---------+---------+-------+--------------+------+-------  
    0       ¦ 01/01/2017 ¦ January ¦    1    ¦ 2017  ¦ Consultant 1 ¦ Temp ¦   450  
    0       ¦ 01/01/2017 ¦ January ¦    1    ¦ 2017  ¦ Consultant 1 ¦ Perm ¦  1000  
    0       ¦ 01/01/2017 ¦ January ¦    1    ¦ 2017  ¦ Consultant 2 ¦ Temp ¦     0  
    0       ¦ 01/01/2017 ¦ January ¦    1    ¦ 2017  ¦ Consultant 2 ¦ Perm ¦  2500  
    0       ¦ 01/01/2017 ¦ January ¦    1    ¦ 2017  ¦ Consultant 3 ¦ Temp ¦  5258  
    0       ¦ 01/01/2017 ¦ January ¦    1    ¦ 2017  ¦ Consultant 3 ¦ Perm ¦  5890  
    0       ¦ 01/01/2017 ¦ January ¦    1    ¦ 2017  ¦ Consultant 4 ¦ Temp ¦  8706  
    0       ¦ 01/01/2017 ¦ January ¦    1    ¦ 2017  ¦ Consultant 4 ¦ Perm ¦  6855
```

What I would like to do is essentially query the GP table for how much each company has made (by temp or perm) and the contribution of each consultant

```
[{
    "Company_Name" : "Company",
    "TotalGP" : "Total_GP",
    "Consultant_Contributions" : [{
            "Consultant_Name" : "Consultant",
            "Toal_GP" : "GP"
        }, {
            "Consultant_Name" : "Consultant",
            "Toal_GP" : "GP"
        }
    ]
}]
```

As I'm pretty new to this kind of thing I've only managed to get to the point where I can get how much each company has made, but not in JSON format;

```sql
SELECT    sum(`Total`) as Total_GP , company    
FROM      `GP`
LEFT JOIN `Defaults` on GP.Consultant = Defaults.Consultant 
WHERE     quarter="1" AND type="temp"
GROUP BY  Company
ORDER BY  company ASC
```

Which gives me this:

```
  Total_GP ¦ company
-----------+----------
   1962.52 ¦ Company 1  
 101703.54 ¦ Company 3  
 378522.45 ¦ Company 2
```

Any help much appreciated.

Comment: I reformatted your post from an Android phone now. See, how beautyful is it now. :-)

Comment: You should have some PHP code to perform the conversion of a record set to a JSON string. Try it. If you have an issue with that, ask a specific question.